# execute a function when all ajax queries are done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my code I have to due several ajax call, then call an update function once all are done. I tried to use `ajaxStop`, but the problem is that the method isn't call if the loop didn't make any ajax call...

It looks like this :

```
for (var key in data) {
  if (...) {
    $.ajax({ ... });
  }
}

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
  updateAll(); // I need to call this function even if there was no ajax call
});
```

Anybody know how to call a function once all ajax from the previous loop are done (even if there was no queries at all) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the returned promises to an array, then use `$.when` to determine when they are all done

```
var xhr = [];

for (var key in data) {
  if (...) {
      var request = $.ajax({ ... });

      xhr.push(request);
  }
}

$.when.apply($, xhr).done(updateAll);
```